# How to Close all opened Windows except one apps by ONE CMD Command,

Tags: windows, command-line

ONE CMD Command wants to close all opened windows but did not close to particular window.

I search in superuser.com and I got this wonderful command from PetSerAl

```
powershell -command "(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\"} | stop-process"
```

this above command closing all opened window but I need to close all windows except one window.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same syntax in you command itself.
If you look into it, it says something like "close every process excluding where the title is empty"

So you could simply ad and AND condition to say to not close where the title is empty AND the title is the one of the process you want to keep open.
In case the title is not fixed and it changes (like for example the windows of an editot, it changes with the name of the file opened in that moment) you could change the property checked, instead of MainWindowTitle you could check for ProcessName

something like this using the window title:

```
powershell -command "(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {($_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\") -and ($_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"titleOfAppToKeepOpen\")} | stop-process"
```

something like this using the process name:

```
powershell -command "(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}; Get-Process | Where-Object {($_.MainWindowTitle -ne \"\") -and ($_.ProcessName -ne \"processToKeepOpen\")} | stop-process"
```